# Integer programming , a transport problem

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-programming

A truck with a maximum capacity of 10 boxes must transport food boxes, medicine boxes and boxes of surgical supplies. You cannot transport more than 5 boxes of the same type and if you transport more than 3 boxes of medicine you must carry at least 4 boxes of food.

---

My work

Let $b:=\text{number of boxes of food}$

$a:=\text{number of boxes of medicines}$

$c:=\text{number of boxes of surgical suplies}$

Then 
$$a+b+c\leq 10$$
$$a\leq 5$$
$$b\leq 5$$
$$c \leq 5 $$
 My question is how transform this
$$\text{if}\;a>3\;\text{then } b\geq 4$$
in a restriction for the linear programming problem?

Comment: Is there something which has to be optimized?

Comment: Looks like you have $a$ and $b$ interchanged.

Comment: So you have no objective function?

Comment: @callculus I have to maximize the number of boxes that the trucks must carry (there are 4 trucks, 2 with capacity for 10 boxes and another 2 with capacity for 9 boxes) and the 4 trucks must comply with the rule of 5 boxes and the condition of boxes. of food and medicine.

Comment: @callculus So I thought I should only repeat the restrictions for the 4 trucks right?

Comment: @callculus there are 12 boxes  of food, 17  boxes of medicines and 11 boxes of surgical suplies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can model $a>3 \implies b\ge 4$ with one binary variable $\delta$ and two linear constraints:
\begin{align}
a - 3 &\le (5-3)\delta \tag1\\
4 - b &\le (4-0)(1-\delta) \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $a>3 \implies \delta=1$,
and constraint $(2)$ enforces $\delta=1 \implies b\ge 4$.

---

If you also want to model the converse $b\ge 4 \implies a>3$, include these two linear constraints:
\begin{align}
b - 3 &\le (5-3)\delta \tag3\\
4 - a &\le (4-0)(1-\delta) \tag4
\end{align}
Constraint $(3)$ 
enforces $b \ge 4 \implies \delta=1$,
and 
constraint $(4)$ 
enforces $\delta=1 \implies a > 3$.

Comment: I think you might need to penalize $\delta$ in the objective function. Otherwise you could have for example $a=1$ and $\delta=1.$

Comment: Only one direction of the implication is required, not the converse.

Comment: Yes, but if $a=1$, you do not want to impose $b \ge 4$. If $\delta$ is not minimized, then nothing prevents the solver from setting $\delta = 1$ (the first constraint becomes $-2 \le 2\delta$, so $\delta = 0$ and $\delta=1$ are valid), which would over constrain the problem.

Comment: $a=1$ does not force $b \ge 4$ in my formulation.  As long as $a\le3$, $\delta$ is free to take either value, whichever the solver decides.

Comment: I agree with you. But if the solver decides to set $\delta=1$ when $a\le 3$, then the second constraint becomes active, which we don't want. Which is why I suggest to minimize $\delta$, so that $\delta$ takes value $1$ only when $a\ge 4$.

Comment: The solver will not do that if it makes the OP's objective worse.  I will add optional constraints to enforce the converse in case the OP wants to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Since $a \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, you can add binary variables $\delta_i$ such that 
$$
a= \delta_1 +2\delta_2 + 3\delta_3 + 4\delta_4 +5\delta_5 \\
 \delta_0 + \delta_1 +\delta_2 +\delta_3 + \delta_4 +\delta_5 = 1
$$

Then, the constraint

> (strictly) more than $3$ boxes of medecine $\Rightarrow$ at least $4$
>   boxes of food

can be modeled as follows:

$$
b\ge 4 \delta_4 \\
b\ge 4 \delta_5 \\
\delta_i \in \{0,1\} 
$$

For example, if $\delta_4 = 1$, then $a=4$, and you have $b\ge 4$. If $\delta_1 =1$, then $a=1$, and $b$ is unconstrained.

Comment: You can strengthen your formulation by replacing the two inequalities on $b$ with $b \ge 4(\delta_4+\delta_5)$.

Comment: Beautiful ! Nice one

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @JhonKnows See also RobPratt 's answer, which is clever and instructive!